# PHP - get array in object

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

I have the following object display as a Json Object :

```
Vtiger_RequestObject([
  valuemap: Vtiger_Request: private
]=>Array([
  __vtrftk
]=>sid: 172e53bdd05f5ef334859018d08043fb563b23b9,
1468335904[
  picklistDependency
]=>[

][
  module
]=>Calendar[
  action
]=>SaveAjax[
  defaultCallDuration
]=>5[
  defaultOtherEventDuration
]=>5[
  userChangedEndDateTime
]=>0[
  subject
]=>jhala12345tst[
  assigned_user_id
]=>1[
  date_start
]=>12-07-2016[
  time_start
]=>05: 05PM[
  due_date
]=>12-07-2016[
  time_end
]=>05: 10PM[
  eventstatus
]=>Dovoláno[
  activitytype
]=>Call[
  cf_1181
]=>Odchozí[
  followup_date_start
]=>[
  followup_time_start
]=>[
  popupReferenceModule
]=>Potentials[
  contact_id
]=>[
  contact_id_display
]=>[
  relatedContactInfo
]=>[
  parent_id
]=>[
  parent_id_display
]=>)[
  rawvaluemap: Vtiger_Request: private
]=>Array([
  __vtrftk
]=>sid: 172e53bdd05f5ef334859018d08043fb563b23b9,
1468335904[
  picklistDependency
]=>[

][
  module
]=>Calendar[
  action
]=>SaveAjax[
  defaultCallDuration
]=>5[
  defaultOtherEventDuration
]=>5[
  userChangedEndDateTime
]=>0[
  subject
]=>jhala12345tst[
  assigned_user_id
]=>1[
  date_start
]=>12-07-2016[
  time_start
]=>05: 05PM[
  due_date
]=>12-07-2016[
  time_end
]=>05: 10PM[
  eventstatus
]=>Dovoláno[
  activitytype
]=>Call[
  cf_1181
]=>Odchozí[
  followup_date_start
]=>[
  followup_time_start
]=>[
  popupReferenceModule
]=>Potentials[
  contact_id
]=>[
  contact_id_display
]=>[
  relatedContactInfo
]=>[
  parent_id
]=>[
  parent_id_display
]=>)[
  defaultmap: Vtiger_Request: private
]=>Array())
```

I want explore array with foreach and search with `array_key_exists()` for `[cf_1181] => Odchozí`. Is it possible?

How I can realize that ?

Comment: As you took so little effort in formatting your question properly, here is a low-effort answer: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Sry, someone edits my post and change description to json object.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the class that created this object?
Simple way - add getter to the class, but if you can not change a class, you can use Reflection api. **But it is slow!**

```
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass('Vtiger_Request');
$reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('valuemap');
$reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
var_dump($reflectionProperty->getValue($obj)); // TODO $obj - is you object
```

Comment: What I must define as an object? If I define `$obj = 'cf_1181';` for example, it does not work...

Comment: $obj - must have instance of Vtiger_Request. You write "i have this object : Vtiger_Request" - this is variable $obj in my example

Comment: Ok, I test `$obj = 'Vtiger_Request';` and it doesn't work too and also php don't print any errors.

Comment: Please read my previous comment. $obj - must be INSTANCE of class Vtiger_Request. Not string. How you display object in questions? This object have variable? $obj = variable in var_dump...

Comment: When I in my code use your 
`$reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('valuemap');`
, **print_r stop working**. 
My code
`<?php
session_start();
$data = $_SESSION['jhalaQCtst'];

class Vtiger_Request { 
}     

$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass('Vtiger_Request');
//$reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('valuemap');
//$reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
//var_dump($reflectionProperty->getValue($obj));

print_r($data);
?>`

Comment: $data is the Vtiger_Requedt instance? if yes - write before var_dump: $obj=$data;

Answer (score 0):

for vtiger only this is for version 7.x
you can get all data by a `Vtiger_Request` method:

```
getall()
```

or

```
get($key, $defvalue = '')
```

something like

```
$data_all_data = $request->getAll();
```

or

```
 $data_by_key = $request->get($key);
```